# jQuery - how to pass $(this) as an object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to pass an object into a function but think there's a problem with $(this) not actually being valid at the point of passing it in.

```
$('textarea[name*=quote]').live('bind',function(){

}).limit('10',$(this).parents('form').children().find('span[name*=qc]') );
```

The second parameter can be either a string or an object like $('span#qc'), but I also want to be able to pass in an object which references the current one.

Why? Because I have several forms on same page, each containing textarea#quote, so depending on which form is selected I want to be able to reference a particular element within the same form.

Anyone??

Comment: You should not have duplicate IDs; use class names instead.

Comment: What's `this` ? I mean, are you in a jQuery.each ? Provide more code, there is no way to tell what actually is `this` in that scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a separate call for each individual instance using `.each`, like this:

```
$('textarea#quote').each(function() {
    $(this).live('bind',function(){

    }).limit('10',$(this).parents('form').children().find('span#qc') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks, will that live update any new textarea#quote fields added to the dom via ajax etc even though it's inside the .each ?

Comment: @regan - It will not, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is an event handler, it cannot run a plugin on new elements...unless it's executed via an event `.live()` can listen for, which is not usually what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

To bind all of them with access to `$(this)`, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), like this:

```
$('textarea[name*=quote]').each(function() {
   $(this).limit('10',$(this).closest('form').find('span[name*=qc]'));
});
```

If you want [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)-like functionality on the second part, you need to either use [`.livequery()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/), like this:

```
$('textarea[name*=quote]').livequery(function() {
   $(this).limit('10',$(this).closest('form').find('span[name*=qc]'));
});
```

Or alternatively, bind them like the first example and also bind when loading new elements, e.g. if you're using [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: blah.html
  success: function(data) {
    //do something with data
    $('textarea[name*=quote]', data).each(function() {
     $(this).limit('10',$(this).closest('form').find('span[name*=qc]'));
   });
  }
});
```

The key here is `, data`, [it provides a context to search in](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), so this is only executing on elements found in the returned data.  You can also wrap this in a function to prevent duplication of code, like this:

```
function bindStuff(context) {
  $('textarea[name*=quote]', context || document).each(function() {
    $(this).limit('10',$(this).closest('form').find('span[name*=qc]'));
  });
}
```

In `document.ready`, call `bindStuff(document)`, in `$.ajax`, you'd call `bindStuff(data)`.